# Can I order a grid of divs by column using flexbox properties?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

This is what I need to achieve:
[image]
(Note the empty grey slots)

Which in flexbox layout should normally behave like this: (if `flex-wrap` is set to `wrap`)

[image]

I know that this could be [achieved](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/) with a CSS grid layout

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 400px;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:nth-child(1) { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
div:nth-child(2) { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
div:nth-child(3) { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
div:nth-child(4) { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
div:nth-child(5) { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
div:nth-child(6) { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
div:nth-child(7) { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div> 
</div>
```

The thing is that I would like to use with `justify-content: space-between` or `gap` as in my scenario the child elements are narrower and not feeling so comfortable with css grid.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33% - 4px);
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

/* just to illustrate: child(6) */
.parent div:nth-child(6) { transform: translate(calc(-100% - 8px), calc(100% + 8px)); }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div> 
</div>
```

Can this be done with flex?

There are 7 elements now but there will be more eventually, so this needs to be scaleable. Also, I'd rather not have to change the markup if possible.

Comment: Will you need the divs ordered in a particular way? E.g. go down column 1 first, then go down column 2, etc., or will they be ordered by row first and somehow "know" to skip column 3 for the 2nd row in your example?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*The thing is that I would like to use with justify-content: space-between or gap as in my scenario the child elements are narrower and not feeling so confortable with css grid*" Do you mean you want to use `gap` but don't feel confident in using the CSS property? Or you want to use gap but don't like how it looks? Or that you _don't_ want to use gap?

Comment: Regardless, in short, no this is not 'properly' do-able in flex, because flex is row-based. This is exactly why want to use grid here. Keep in mind you can _combine_ grid properties and flexbox properties in one layout to achieve the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

Let me do a little summary of the request:

You have a flex container with 3 columns. When there are 3n + 1 items, the last 2 elements must be in the last row, leaving a gap in the previous row.

You can get this result using 2 pseudo elements as fillers (the second one could be skipped for some flex configurations). You need to use order to set them correctly, using some advanced nth-child selectors.

See in the snippet how this selectors trigger, as the background color shows.

The pseudo elements have a border of 0 pixels, You can change this for them to be visible.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33% - 4px);
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.parent div:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
    order: 3;
}
.parent div:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(1) {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    order: 3;
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33% - 4px);
  height: 0px;
  order: 2;
}


.parent:after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33% - 4px);
  height: 0px;
  order: 4;
}

.parent:before, .parent:after {
  border: 0px solid red; /* change to 1px to show them */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div> 
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div> 
   <div>8</div> 
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div> 
   <div>8</div> 
   <div>9</div> 
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div> 
   <div>8</div> 
   <div>9</div> 
   <div>10</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't technically be semantically incorrect to use the [`<hr>` element as a line-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) for your flex children. It essentially acts as a placeholder, and will force the following flex children to a new line.

Using `margin` or `padding` with `transform` to try and break it to the next line may cause overlapping issues when resizing.

In CSS2 we were able to use `break-after` and `break-before` for these types of things. But it is not widely supported in CSS3.

I hope there is this sort of functionality in the future, but for now, CSS grid handles this type of design well.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent > div {
  background-color: #1b6b34;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}

.parent > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #685219;
}

hr {
  border: transparent;
  width: .1px;
}

.parent > div:nth-child(6) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div><hr>
   <div></div>
   <div></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: "Not semantically incorrect" is about the kindest way you can put it for sure... don't think I agree, though props for the idea. Unfortunately this doesn't scale well automatically when there are dynamic number of elements that need to be placed into columns; as OP mentions in the comments above, there will 'eventually be more' divs, not just 7.

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on pseudo-elements and this can work up to 9 elements. I am adding some coloration to better understand the trick:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33% - 4px);
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.parent:before,
.parent:after {
  content: "";
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* to illustrate */ border-bottom:2px solid red;
}

.parent :nth-child(-n + 5) {
  order:-1;
  /* to illustarte */ background: lightgreen;
}
.parent :nth-child(n + 8) {
  order:1;
  /* to illustarte */ background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to leave the middle column empty rather than the right column.

Comment: @TylerH the trick is to have only 2 items in the second and third row. The OP said he wants to use justify-content so I am adding it to show that it works. If you remove it you will get the third column empty

Answer (score -1):

[`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) can wrap it downward in the desired shape

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

and if needed you can [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) within

Comment: in my example are just empty boxes, but they actually have texts that shouldn't be rotated. but  didn't know about this rule, thanks!